# <[object Object]> appear instead of downloadurl

Tags: typescript, firebase

downloadurl not coming out in console, instead [object,Object] [screenshot image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBaUR.png)

```
this.dbs.collection("databases").get().toPromise().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc=>{ 
    let name=doc.data().path;
    this.down=this.storage.ref(name).getDownloadURL();
    console.log(name);
    console.log(this.down);
  })
```

Comment: prefer copy and paste of error message instead of putting error image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference), `getDownloadURL()` returns a promise, so you'll need to wait for that promise to resolve before attempting to access it:

```
this.storage.ref(name).getDownloadURL().then((link) => {
  this.down = link;
}
```